# SQL Server CE 4 DataProvider not available in server explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dataprovider, sql-server-ce

I have installed the sp1 for visual studio 2010 and installed sql server ce 4 runtime. But still not able to create connection to the sql ce database using standart data provider.

This is how my Select DataProvider Dialog looks like now.
[image: Change data source dialog]

P.S. 
Does not know if it matters, but I have tested this with console application and winforms application both targeted at .Net 4.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must install the SQL Server Compact 4 tools via Web PI, as described here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html

Comment: updated link http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/D/05DCCDB5-57E0-4314-A016-874F228A8FAD/SSCEVSTools-ENU.msi

Comment: Are you talking about *scripting* tools?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this project/Tool to open/create sql ce databases:

[SQL SERVER CE QUERY TOOL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CEQuery.aspx)

And have a look at this:

[Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)

Regards

Comment: This can be helpfull, but this one should be supported by visual studio, or atleast ms sql server management studio (which is also installed). I do not belive that technology creator does not include it support in tooling.

Comment: Yup this is just a tool even without visual studio and ssms. But its function is almost the same and easy to use as what we are using ssms.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, just install the extension SQL Server Compact & SQLite Toolbox

from here http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com or over VS Add Extension.